# Script ( sticky.js ) used in WordPress Theme not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to use **sticky.js** with my **wordpress** site. I've successfully added then via the functions file and they show up in my footer as they should. My problem is getting the snipet of code that came with sticky.js to run:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0});
  });
</script>
```

I put this code at the bottom of my header section in header.php and it did not work so I added and included another js file called run-sticky.js and have added this to my functions which successfully added the script to the footer.

I replaced #sticker with #nav-wrapper because that is the div that I want to be fixed to the top of the page once a user scrolls to that point like the buttons on the creator's site:

http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky

Here is the site I'm working on.

http://futurehistoryfestival.com

Comment: Belongs on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your console it says "$ is not a function". Seems like jQuery is running in noconflict mode. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#nav-inner-wrapper").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
});
```

Comment: By default WordPress runs in NoConflict mode.